# How to configure JVM memory settings in Bluemix?

Tags: jvm, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am using Cloud Foundry on Bluemix, and my app is constantly running out of metaspace. I am using OpenJDK 1.8 buildpack (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git), which has a default metaspace setting of 64M.

How do I configure and tune the JVM's memory settings to give it more metaspace?

Thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was digging into the java buildpack and ran into an [issue on github](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues/268) that described the fix.  You need to set it with the following for 128m.

```
cf set-env appname JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE '[memory_calculator: {memory_heuristics: {heap: 70, metaspace: 15, native: 10, permgen: 15, stack: 5}, memory_sizes: {metaspace: 128m}}]'
```